# How has SE designed the inbox basket picture that the quality keeps nice when zoomed?

Tags: html, css, image

I wonder the way the Stack Exchange inbox basket icon(/picture) is designed.

Because if it was an icon or a picture, its quality would decrease with zoom.

It's not a letter (of a font family) either!

So I tried inspect elements of firefox and it led me to this page:

http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=698e8b939ec0

MY first thought was this is a picture that a specific coordinate of it is shown in different places if needed. but, that is not a picture nor an icon because I couldn't select it nor save it.

i.e. when I right click on it, there is no save as picture button.

What is it then?

Comment: It _is_ an image. It's an SVG, so it scales nicely. It is used as you suspect - parts of the whole image are shown as different elements on the page. You can't easily save it because it's applied as the background-image of the link, rather than as an image element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called 'scalable vector graphics'. Images created by saying:

```
This line starts [here] and ends [here] and is this [color] & [thickness]
```

Not quite but essentially that kind of thing. Way better than files full of pixels!

Also, it's a single file which means fewer calls to the server... potentially a LOT fewer if you have a lot of small image files loading all the time eg logos, buttons etc....